# Create separate DF with data from original - remove original data at same time

Tags: r

I am trying to move test DF data to test2 DF data in one code chunk - Right now, I have this going as two separate code chunks - the top one creates the test2 data from test data. Then the bottom chunk simply removes that same data from test.

```
test2 <- test[0,colnames(test)]
test2 <- test[nchar(test$insert_text1) != 10 | 
                grepl(pattern = "text1", x = test$insert_text2`, ignore.case = T) == FALSE | 
                grepl(pattern = "text2", x = test$insert_text3, ignore.case = T) == TRUE |
                is.na(test$insert_text1),]

test <- test[-c(nchar(test$insert_text1) != 10 | 
                  is.na(test$insert_text1) |
                  grepl(pattern = "text2", x = test$insert_text2, ignore.case = T) == TRUE |
                  grepl(pattern = "text1", x = test$insert_text1, ignore.case = T) == FALSE) == FALSE,]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a data frame and removing data from a data frame are 2 separate concepts - they should not be combined into one operation.

You can, however, simplify your code but moving the row identification to the top and not write/run the same logic twice. I've also done some other simplification: `== FALSE` is a long way to write `!`, `== TRUE` is never needed (if `x == TRUE` is `TRUE` that means `x` is already `TRUE`), and I use `with()` to skip the need for `data$` in the command.

```
rows = with(test,
  nchar(insert_text1) != 10 | 
  !grepl(pattern = "text1", x = insert_text2, ignore.case = T) | 
  grepl(pattern = "text2", x = insert_text3, ignore.case = T) |
  is.na(insert_text1)
)

test2 = test[rows, ]
test = test[!rows, ]
```